# Apache poi how to set sheets to an enum location value attribute?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, pojo

I am iterating through workbook read data from multiple sheets and merge all rows in the same table using the code below.

```
  public boolean readDataFromExcel(MultipartFile file) {
    Workbook workbook = getWorkBook(file);

    for (int i = 0 ; i < workbook.getNumberOfSheets(); i++) {
      Sheet mySheet = workbook.getSheetAt(i);

      Iterator<Row> rows = mySheet.iterator();
      rows.next();
      while (rows.hasNext()) {
        Row row = rows.next();
        if (isRowEmpty(row)) {
          continue;
        }

       getItemCellValue(row, file, workbook);

      }
    }
    return true;
  }
```

the getItemCellValue method gets cell type and sets it to its respective attribute

```
  private boolean getItemCellValue(Row row, MultipartFile file, Workbook workbook) {
   try {
      if (row.getCell(0).getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC) {
        item.setItemNumber((float) row.getCell(0).getNumericCellValue());
      }

      if (row.getCell(1).getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC) {
          item.setHeight(row.getCell(1).getNumericCellValue());
      } if (row.getCell(15).getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING) {
        item.setItemDesc(row.getCell(15).getStringCellValue());
      }
      itemRepository.save(item);
   } catch (NullPointerException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
      return true;
}
```

I have an enum attribute (Location) that maps to 2 locations for example and my input file should have 2 different sheets(tabs). the objective here is to set the location of an item from the sheet which it was read and parsed from.

Ex. if I have 2 sheets for example and item1 is parsed from sheet1 and item2 from sheet2 then the location field should be set to display the correct location from which the item row exits(either sheet1 or sheet2 in this case).

```
| item.      | itemNo.     | location     |
|:-----------|------------:|:------------:|
| item1      |    1111     |  LOCATION1   |
| item2      |    2222     |  LOCATION2   |
```

**the solution would probably be to detect which sheet each row belongs to and set the location there, but then I couldn't find anything that returns that in the APACHE POI?**

Comment: [Row.getSheet](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Row.html#getSheet--)?

Comment: nice but how would you get the sheet index so you can say rows(i) belong to sheet(i), the getSheet returns Sheet, which encapsulate getSheetName

Comment: [Sheet.getWorkbook](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Sheet.html#getWorkbook--) -> [Workbook.getSheetIndex](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Workbook.html#getSheetIndex-org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet-)?

Comment: @AxelRichter much appreciated works perfectly